# How to UPDATE sql only WHERE has a different row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Ok I am trying to `UPDATE` my table columns only if the `myCheck` row is different

```
$query = "UPDATE `mytable` 
    SET myCheck='" . $myCheck . "', myStatus='" . $myStatus . "', myId='" . $myId . "'
    WHERE my_id = '" . $myId . "'
    AND myCheck != '" . $myCheck . "' ";
```

The columns  exist, and I need to `UPDATE` them where `my_id row = $myId` (this works)

I want to check if this data is already in my sql, so I create `myCheck` row
but query update no matter `myCheck` row is equal to `$myCheck`, or not.

I tried <> instead != ... the same result

Also I want when `$myId` is different from these in sql (for example in sql my_id rows are `1,2,3` and `$myId = 4`) to create a new row with `my_id 4`.

Maybe I must use something different from `UPDATE`?

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need 'INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I understood what the problem was :)

myCheck row was varchar(32), and $myCheck has 35 symbols... so always

11111111111111111111111111111111 =! 11111111111111111111111111111111111

now myCheck row is varchar(64) and everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

I think that `myCheck` could be `null`, and since `null <> something` is never true your rows won't be updated. Try this instead:

```
UPDATE `mytable` set SET myCheck='your_value'
WHERE my_id = 'your_id' AND ((myCheck <> 'your_value') OR myCheck is null)
```

Comment: if this is not what you are looking for, i think you are looking for an `INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (your_values)` query, and not an UPDATE query...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use '<>' instead of '!='

Comment: I tried, sorry to forget to post that in my question... I will edit now